# Why isn't my spinner updating with my arrayList items?

Tags: android, arraylist, spinner, loading

I have the current method and sActivity has a public arrayList that I want to use.
I just can't figure it out, my spinner does not have any values in it. This spinner is in another activity than where I am adding items to the arraylist. So maybe I have to `intent.putExtra("arrayL", savedColors)` so that i have to send arraylist to this activity...I don't know just guessing. Any help is much appreciated. I have hard coded some ColorSaver objects into the arrayList, so i know there is values in it.

```
private void addColorNames()
{
    Spinner colorsSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.colorsSpinner);

    ArrayAdapter<ColorSaver> dataAdapter 
        = new ArrayAdapter<ColorSaver>
        (RecallActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sActivity.savedColors);

    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    colorsSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

}//End addColorNames()

public class RecallActivity extends Activity {


ArrayList<String> namesArray = new ArrayList<String>();
SaveActivity sActivity = new SaveActivity();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recall);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();
    final Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    final Spinner colorList = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.colorsSpinner);
    Button grabButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.grabButton);

    //Load the spinner with the saved colors
    addColorNames();


    //namesArray.addAll(sActivity.nameArray);
    //colorsSpinner.add;
    grabButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            //ColorSaver saver = new ColorSaver(colorName, redcolor, greencolor, bluecolor);
            //savedColors.add(saver);
            //startActivity(intent1);
            ColorSaver selectedItem = (ColorSaver) colorList.getSelectedItem();

            int redValue, greenValue, blueValue;
            String name;
            redValue = selectedItem.getRedValue();
            greenValue = selectedItem.getGreenValue();
            blueValue = selectedItem.getBlueValue();
            name = selectedItem.getColorName();
            intent1.putExtra("savedRValue", redValue);
            intent1.putExtra("savedGValue", greenValue);
            intent1.putExtra("savedBValue", blueValue);
            intent1.putExtra("savedName", name);
            startActivity(intent1);


        }//END onClick
    });
}

/**
 * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}.
 */
private void setupActionBar() {

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.recall, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
        // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
        // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
        //
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}// END onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)


public void addColorNames()
{
    Spinner colorsSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.colorsSpinner);

    ArrayAdapter<ColorSaver> dataAdapter 
        = new ArrayAdapter<ColorSaver>
        (RecallActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sActivity.savedColors);

    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    colorsSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

}//End addColorNames()
```

}//END CLASS

The Class where I am saving items to the array is

```
public class SaveActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = "Save Activity";
public ArrayList<ColorSaver> savedColors = new ArrayList<ColorSaver>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_save);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();

    final Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    Button saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton1);
    final EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.colorNameField);
    final Intent intent = new Intent();

    //Making sure the savedColors arrayList has something in it.
    ColorSaver temp = new ColorSaver("TestColor", 180, 80, 255);
    savedColors.add(temp);


    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click

            int redcolor, greencolor, bluecolor;
            redcolor = intent.getIntExtra("RedValue", 255);
            greencolor = intent.getIntExtra("GreenValue", 255);
            bluecolor = intent.getIntExtra("BlueValue", 255);
            String colorName = nameField.getText().toString();

            ColorSaver saver = new ColorSaver(colorName, redcolor, greencolor, bluecolor);
            savedColors.add(saver);
            Log.i(TAG, savedColors.get(savedColors.size()-1).getColorName());
            startActivity(intent1);

        }
    });

}//END OnCreate()

/**
 * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}.
 */
private void setupActionBar() {

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.save, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
        // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
        // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
        //
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}//END CLASS

Comment: Create a log and print **sActivity.savedColors** arraylist values to check whether the values are accessed inside this method.

Comment: Post your whole Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possibility that the `ArrayList` from sActivity is `null` when you access it from another activity.

Check whether it is `null` or has values inside, or just use `Intent` to pass the array to the activity with `Spinner`. (It is safer to use `Intent`'s extra data)

Comment: I did use the log and I found out that it is null in the recallActivity. I'm not quite sure how to fix that because my arraylist contains Color objects and not primative data types like the ones I can pass through the intent.

Comment: Try to serialize `ColorSaver` by implementing `Serializable`. Use `Intent.putExtra()` as usual to transfer the data, but use `Intent.getSerializableExtra()` and cast to `ArrayList<ColorSaver>` when retrieving the data.